# How to create call to action button into mobile menu

Tags: jquery, append

I have a call to action button that is fine in desktop version but How can I move it on mobile menu. I try to make it by jquery append after methods but the call to cation increase each time when mobile button clicked. My questions is How it can be stop when click on mobile menu icon[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4DOk.png).

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".btn-menu").click(function(){
        jQuery("+41 79 320 57 91").insertAfter(".menu-hauptmenue-container");
    });
});

Comment: Please try to more clear. It would be better if you can show some code.

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".btn-menu").click(function(){
        jQuery("<span>+41 79 320 57 91</span>").insertAfter(".menu-hauptmenue-container");
    });
});
</script>